# XCode not recognizing my iphone

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, ios5.1

XCode was recognizing my device just a day ago but now its not. I am getting the error in the organizer below. I know there are many other questions like this but non of them are answering my question. I am unable to see "**Use for Development**" button, neither **adding to portal** is fixing the issue.  **I have upgraded the device when 5.1 came and was able to use the device for testing but dont know what happend yesterday and it stop recognizing the device.**

```
The version of iOS on “Adil Muhammad’s iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Adil Muhammad’s iPhone
5.1 (9B176)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2
```

Comment: one trick i found -it may work if try attaching your device to other system's x code which can detect than try again with your non detecting system it may work.

Comment: @NSMutableArrayRetained - strange! But I have no other machine and it was working...

Comment: if you have more than one system you can try this. same problem i had found and it worked.i did't found the problem by the way.

Comment: @NSMutableArrayRetained - I have done everything possible.

Answer (score 2):

you updated your phone, so you need the latest xcode installed to now develop apps on your dev phone

Comment: yes and it was working OK from last 1 month with upgrade OS and I was using the device for testing. Something happen tomorrow and its not longer working!

Comment: sounds like the only thing you can do is upgrade xcode to the latest which will have support for the newly upgraded device.

Answer (score 0):

As your Device ios version is higher than what your xcode support.

Upgrade you xcode with the latest one (xcode 4.3).

This is the only Resason
Regards,
neil.

Comment: as I have mentioned in my questions, it was working OK with latest update and I was able to use the device for testing but something happen tomorrow and its no longer able to detect the device...